# PHP - Set session within a function

Tags: php, session

got a (I guess...) very simple problem:

I want to set a session within a function.
Simple situation:

I got a login form. After subimitting the form, I call a function "login" which checks if user has authenticated. If yes, a session should be set.

Here some very simple code:

```
session_start();

function login() {
  $SESSION['login'] = true;
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['doLogin'])) {
  login();
  // is session is set here, it works...
}

if ($SESSION['login'] === true) echo 'you are logged in';
```

But this doesn't work. Why?
Thanks alot!

Comment: I like that you caught `$_REQUEST` but not `$SESSION`, also its considered bad practice to use `$_REQUEST`, instead you should use `$_POST`, `$_GET`, or `$_COOKIE` depending on what you are doing...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are using `$SESSION` you need to be using `$_SESSION`

Comment: Uh damn I'm really embarrassed. Haven't coded php for month and obvisously I've lost my eye for it. thank you and sorry this   superfluous "question" ;)

Comment: It happens to the best of us :)